# конструкторы с разной сигнатурой но одинаковой логикой C#

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование

Имеются четыре конструктора производного класса с разной сигнатурой но повторяющейся логикой, в базовом классе имеется два конструктора с разной сигнатурой и логикой.
Возможно ли избежать повторения кода в конструкторах при таком варианте?
Пример для лучшего понимания.
Базовый класс:

```
public class Pawn
{
    private static int _counter;
    private readonly int _id;
    private string _name;

    public Pawn()
    {
        _counter++;
        _id = _counter;
        _name = Convert.ToString(_counter);
    }

    public Pawn(string name):this()
    {
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

Производный класс:

```
public class PawnMove : Pawn
{
    private int x=0;
    private int y=0;
    //private int z=0;

    public PawnMove()
    {

    }

    public PawnMove(int x, int y) : this()
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public PawnMove(string name):base(name)
    {

    }

    public PawnMove(string name, int x, int y) : this(name)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: является ли значение `null` допустимым для параметра `name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если учесть что ты один инициализатор наследуешь то от другого из этого класса то от другого из базового класса.... То единственным путем есть создание еще одного метода который бы вызывался в нужных местах.

```
public class PawnMove : Pawn
{
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    public PawnMove(){}

    public PawnMove(int x, int y) : this()
    {
        Move(x, y);
    }
    public PawnMove(string name) :base(name)
    {

    }

    public PawnMove(string name, int x, int y) : this(name)
    {
        Move(x, y);
    }

    private void Move(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать значения по-умолчанию

```
public class Pawn
{
    private static int _counter;
    private readonly int _id;
    private string _name;

    public Pawn(string name = "")
    {
        _counter++;
        _id = _counter;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            _name = Convert.ToString(_counter);
        }
        else
        {
            _name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Вместо `name = ""` можно использовать `name = default(string)` или любую другую предопределённую константу. Сравнивать, соответственно, с ней же.

В производном классе получается

```
public class PawnMove : Pawn
{
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    public PawnMove(int x, int y, string name = "") : base(name)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public PawnMove(string name = "") : base(name)
    { }

}
```

Можно использовать значения по-умолчанию и для `x` и `y`, но тогда их становится можно инициализировать по-отдельности, а не сразу парой

```
public class PawnMove : Pawn
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public PawnMove(int x = 0, int y = 0, string name = "") : base(name)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

ну и создавать объекты, которым передается только `name` придется через именованные параметры:

```
PawnMove pm = new PawnMove(name: "pm");
```